# Django: python manage.py runserver works, but python3 manage.py runserver doesn't work

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.4

[Python 2 with Django 1.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pjQx.png)

[Python 3 with Django 2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3WuJ.png)

I wanted to start fun with django on opensuse. The first problem what i have is server runs only on python2. I dont know what to do.
Could anybody help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`unpacking generalization syntax`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) that allows arbitrary number of unpackings in a function call is supported only in Python 3.5+, and you're using Python 3.4.6. Please upgrade your Python.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can't upgrade to Python 3.5+, you can use Django 1.11.x (LTS) and Django 2.0.x with Python 3.4.

Comment: thanks guys it took me a while becouse opensue 42.3 leap and needed to download 15 so... not it works :D thanks guys :)